# Error: "There was a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m saving package data" - Magento

Tags: magento, installation, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/packaging_a_magento_extension) Package the module which I have developed. Module works fine. When I tried to save I get this error `"There was a problem saving package data"` as shown in the screenshot too.

[image]

Documentation says *You will have ”There was a problem saving package data” when you save the extension if there is space inside the module name.* But as you can see there is not spaces in the module name.

What could be the issue? How can I fix this?

Comment: can you please check if there are any whitespaces AFTER name and channel field values? It occurs sometimes unintentionally.

Comment: Ok great, you may have error in other tab data then.

Comment: if you can post all as an answer I can accept

Comment: did you solved the error?

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot for the support. But Now I end up with another issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851580/how-to-the-installer-after-package-data-has-been-created-magento

Comment: i posted the solution of your problem there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: Extensions are case sensitive. Make sure the package name reflects accordingly in all folders and xml files. e.g. MyExtension is not same as Myextension.

NOTE: The package name must NOT have space inside. For example, use Foo_Bar, don’t use “Foo Bar”. You will have ”There was a problem saving package data” when you save the extension if there is space inside the module name.

*Capital letters & spaces matter.*

Answer (score 4):

in linux 
change the connect folder permision to

**chmod -R 777 /var/www/magento/var/connect/**

Comment: I'm sure there's a better solution than blindly `chmod`ing `777`.

Comment: This solution is fine -- when you build extensions, you are really just doing so from a development box.

Answer (score -1):

Heres another example of adding a group, and then deleting a group.

```
// Adding attribute options 
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$attribute  = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "position");

$aClasses = array('Administrator','Dean','Counselor');



$updates = array();
$updates['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getId();

for($cnt = 0; $cnt < sizeof($aClasses); $cnt++) {
        $updates['values'][] = $aClasses[$cnt];
}
$setup->addAttributeOption($updates);


die();




// Deleting attribute options

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$attribute  = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "position");

//Values have to be deleted one at a time
// Eav Setup.php
$updates = array();
foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions() as $option) {
        $update['value'] = array();
        $update['delete'][$option['value']] = true;
        $update['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getId();
        $update['value'][$option['value']] = true;
        $updates[] = $update;
}

$setup->addAttributeOption($updates);
die();
```