# How to the installer after package data has been created - Magento

Tags: magento, installation, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I followed this tutorial and was able to create the package data successfully as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Now I have below three file in the `var/connect` folder. Myname_Mygateway-1.0.0.tgz, Myname_Mygateway.xml, package.xml as shown below.

[image]

I tried to zip all the files and make a installer but It does not work when I tried to install in another magento site.

How to the installer after package data has been created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to zip anything. The file with extension `.tgz` is only responsible to install the extension.

Just go to `Admin > System > Magento Connect > Connect Manager > Direct Package file upload` and upload your `.tgz` file and it will get installed.

If you want to create an extension key, you will need to go to MagentoCommerce website and under Your Account, you will have tab `Developers > Add new extension`. There you can submit your extension and it will need to be verified by the Magento team. It usually takes 3-5 days I guess. Once it's `Live`, you can then see your extension listed in official Magento Connect website.

Comment: I get this error."CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
Empty package contents section". By the way when I unzip the it. It's just an xml file.

Comment: may be you missed `Content` section of the package.

Comment: how can I add this folder "/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mygateway". When I set the path it's not being added. /app/code/local has been added correctly

Comment: `Target: Magento user interface (layouts, templates)` and `Path: frontend/base/default/template/mygateway`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I get this error : "CONNECT ERROR: The 'http://connect.magentocommerce.com/community' channel is not installed. Please use the MAGE shell script to install the 'http://connect.magentocommerce.com/community' channel."

Comment: `Target: Magento community module file` and `Path: Myname/Mygateway`

Comment: that is the permission issue.. lets chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24431/discussion-between-dasun-and-kalpesh-mehta)